# Need suggestion to decrease the app size when migrating from Fabric to Firebase for Crashlytics Only

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Problem:

We planned to migrate our Crashlytics integration from Fabric to Firebase, 
I followed the steps and after successful integration, our ipa size shows a decent increase of about ~13MB.

Possible Reason:

I found that pod 'Firebase/Core' downloads other dependencies listed below :

- Firebase (5.20.2)
- FirebaseAnalytics (5.8.1)
- FirebaseCore (5.4.1)
- FirebaseInstanceID (3.8.1)
- GoogleAppMeasurement (5.8.1)
- GoogleUtilities (5.8.0)
- nanopb (0.3.901)

What I tried:

Tried manual installation to include only FirebaseCore, however, it could not compile until I added all other dependencies listed above.

Podfile :

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.9.3'
```

What I know:

I understand that fabric console can be migrated to Firebase for now, however as per my understanding that will not be supported in future.
I also understand that this might be a strategy of the company (Google) to collect some data from our app.

As per Android team, Only FirebaseCore works fine for them

Help I need:

Is there any way to include only firebase/core only to reduce the extra MBs added to IPA without any added feature (at least for us).
Any suggestions are welcomed where we can continue using Crashlytics with Firebase without an increase in app size

PS: My apologies if this question is somewhat similar to other questions, however, I could not find anyone mentioned the same problem with any solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have migrated from fabric to firebase, you do not need to include 'Firebase/Core' in your podfile.